# $("divId").text();....is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div inside jquery tab and I am trying to get the content using a 
button. When I click on button a javaScript function is getting called, 
inside the function I am trying to grt the content

**HTML code**

```
  <div id="tab1" contenteditable="true">
      <div>line no one</div>
      <div>line no one</div>
  </div>
```

**JavaScript function**

```
  alert($("tab1").text());
  alert($("tab1").html());
```

**error**

For text(); I am not getting any thing but for html(); it is showing Undefined

I am not able to guess whats wrong with the code...
Any suggestions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See you have missed `#` notation for id selector and make sure to have it wrapped in `$(function(){...})` doc ready handler:

```
$(function(){
    alert($("#tab1").text());
    alert($("#tab1").html());
});
```

Comment: +1 Yeah document.ready is most likley missing

Comment: seems like it...anyways thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use ID indication `"#"`

```
alert($("#tab1").text());
//       ^here
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J6NUF/)

Comment: Ohh I am sorry I missed it while posting..It is already there in my code. Still I am getting these Errors.

Comment: @DEV Try Jai's answer it will probably fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

jQuery expects a [selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/), not an id. `"tab1"` is a *type* selector, it matches `<tab1>` elements (which do not exist in HTML).

You can use an ID selector though: `$("#tab1")`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery?

Does it load proprely?

try this

```
   alert($("#tab1").text());
   alert($("#tab1").html());
```

you have to tell jquery that you are looking for an id with "#"